# Java - How to create a 3D vector based on the rotation of a camera

Tags: java, vector, 3d

I am trying to create a vector based on the rotation of my camera, for example if the camera looked straight forward it would be <0, 0, -1> (Note: The axes are based on the opengl ones) or if the camera was looking to the right and a bit up it would be <0.5, 0.5, 0>

I am using the lwjgl library so joml is avaliable. But if its easier just creating x,y,z float's is fine.

Note: The camera only uses x and y rotation as z rotation isn't needed and you cant just construct a vector purely based on those and make z rotation 0, it doesn't work.

In layman's terminology I want a vector that if you added it to the position of a player it would move in the direction that the camera is facing.

Edit:
Correct locations in joml are:

```
x=m02
y=m12
z=m22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forward direction should just be the z axis (3rd column) of your camera matrix. Depending on the API you are using the "camera matrix" might be it's inverse, in that case take the 3rd row.